# An object, within an object, within an array of objects, within an array of objects in Java?

Tags: java

**EDIT:
I see I worded my original question incorrectly, there should have been 2 arrays, I have amended that to be more clear.
I've got everything working now EXCEPT the getter method for the departments and the locations. I have tried numerous ways to display this, but it will only show the address no matter what I try. This is what I have (location is the same, just in a different object with different names):**

```
public void getDepartments () {
    for(int i = 0; i < departments.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(departments.get(i));
    }
}
```

**This works for the Employees arraylist, but not the departments or locations arraylist.**

Working on this project and I honestly have no idea what to do. Essentially breaks down like this:

Create object1 with 2 variables, (lets say this is person, with name and age as variables).

Create object2 as a subclass of object1 with 2 additional variables, (lets call this one employee, with variables employee ID and position)

Create object3 with a name variable and an array of object2, (so name is department, and the array would hold all the employees that work there)

Create object4 which holds an array of object3. (this is an array of office locations)

Essentially I should be able to pull a list showing the office location, with a list of departments at that location, and a list of employees in those departments.

Heres what I have coded:

Object 1:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private int age;

public Person () {
    name = "";
    age = 0;
}

public Person (String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public void setName (String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName () {
    return name;
}

public void setAge (int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getAge () {
    return age;
}

public String toString () {
    return ("Name: " + name + ", Age: " + age);
}
}
```

Object 2:

```
public class Employee extends Person {

private String employeeID;
private String position;

public Employee (){
    super ();
    employeeID = "";
    position = "";
}

public Student (String name, int age, String employeeID, String position){
    super (name, age);
    this.employeeID = employeeID;
    this.position = position;
}

public void setEmployeeID (String employeeID) {
    this.employeeID = employeeID;
}

public String getEmployeeID () {
    return employeeID;
}

public void setPosition (String position) {
    this.year = position;
}

public String getPosition() {
    return year;
}

public String toString () {
    return (super.toString() + ", Employee ID: " + employeeID + ", Position: 
" + position);
}

}
```

Object 3: (obviously a lot missing at this point)

```
public class Department {

private String departmentName;
private int numberOfEmployees;
private Employee[] employees;

public Department() {

}

public Department (String departmentName, int numberOfEmployees) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
    this.numberOfEmployees = numberOfEmployees;
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[numberOfEmployees];
    }

public String getName() {
    return departmentName;
}

public void setName(String departmentName) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

public int getNumberOfEmployees() {
    return numberOfEmployees;
}

public void setNumberOfEmployees(int numberOfEmployees) {
    this.numberOfEmployees = numberOfEmployees;
}

}
```

Comment: Please read about Java Inheritance first

Comment: Do have some basic understanding of OOPS principle first & then try out the same problem on your own. If it doesn’t work out then post your question with your query.

Comment: It would be best to post some code which shows your work.  For example, you say you have no idea how these arrays work, but can you make any kind of array?  Like an array of String?

Comment: It's actually interesting to know that you have found an example to describe that but you have no idea what to do. Perhaps what you need is collections like `List` (i.e. `ArrayList`).

Comment: Re: the code you added: so, just make an array of Department, is that hard?  What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I guess lists is what I need...which after doing some reading is what I was thinking. Just that in my course we haven't been taught how to use them...but I suppose thats typical for this instructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should read carefully OOP principles. It is fundamental but really important for your logic thought.

I just help you to clarify your question.
You need to define a `Person` class like (for object1)

```
public abstract class Person {
   protected String name;
   protected Integer age;
   public Person(String n, Integer a){
      name = n;
      age = a;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
     //print out person's info
   }
   //TODO: you should create getter/setter by yourself.
}
```

Next will be `Employee` class which is subclass of `Person`:

```
public class Employee extends Person {
   private String employeeId;
   private String position;
   public Employee (String name, int age, String id, String pos) {
      //parent constructor
      super(name, age);
      employeeId = id;
      position = pos;
   }
          @Override
   public String toString() {
     //print out employee's info
   }
  //TODO: you should create getter/setter by yourself.
}
```

Third will be `Office`:

```
public class Office {
  private String location;
  //you can use Person here because it is parent of Employee
  private List<Person> employees; 
   //TODO: you should create getter/setter by yourself.
  public Office(String loc) {
    location = loc;
    employees = new ArrayList<Person>();
  } 
  public void addEmployee(Person p) {
    employees.add(p);
  }
}
```

Then in your `main` class, you can declare objects like this:

```
   Person p1 = new Employee("Mr.X", 30, "ID001", "Manager");
   Person p2 = new Employee("Mr.Y", 31, "ID002", "Director");

   Office office = new Office("Silicon Valley");
   office.addEmployee(p1);
   office.addEmployee(p2);

   List<Office> offices =new ArrayList<Office>(); 
   offices.add(office);
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. But I'm still confused because location and Office also need to be arrays of objects. I need to be able to declare multiple locations in main, with an array of object Office within it, and an array of object Employee within that. Not sure how that is accomplished.